# JS Beginner level : Can't replicate this JSfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle

I'm making a personal website where pages are divided into 2. if you click on the left, the left part expands to the right and vice versa.

After the click action a button can supposedly reset the whole thing. It works great in this JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CFNUJ/1/

but I can't replicate it (http://guillaumeb.com/jsfiddle/split.html)

The "Show all" button does nothing...

Also I noticed that more recent versions of JQuery break the whole thing so I make use of v 1.x, like on the original example.

My JS skills are quite limited. Any help is appreciated

Here is the original code:

```js
    $('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
            function(){
                $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
                $('<button class="show">Show all</button>')
                    .appendTo('#wrapper');
            });
        
        $('.show').live('click',
                        function(){
                            $('#left-bg').animate(
                                {
                                    'width': '50%'
                                },600);
                            $('#right-bg').animate(
                                {
                                    'width': '50%'
                                },600);
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
```

```css
#left-bg {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        
        #right-bg {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #fff;
            color: 000;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        
        .show {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -2.5em;
            width: 5em;
        }
```

```html
   <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-bg">
            <p>Left stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right-bg">
            <p>Right stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left-bg">
            <p>Left stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div id="right-bg">
            <p>Right stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you importing JQuery anywhere?

Comment: They break because `live()` was deprecated many years ago

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `JQuery` library reference in your page

Update the function as following:

```
$(function(){
        $('#left-bg, #right-bg').click(
            function(){
            $(this).animate({'width': '100%'},600).siblings().animate({'width':'0'},600);
            $('<button class="show">Show all</button>')
                .appendTo('#wrapper');
        });
          $(document).on('click','.show',
                                function(){
                                    $('#left-bg').animate(
                                        {
                                            'width': '50%'
                                        },600);
                                    $('#right-bg').animate(
                                        {
                                            'width': '50%'
                                        },600);
                                    $(this).remove();
                                });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one may it works
$('.show').on('click',function(){

or

$(document).on('click','.show',function(){

because jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards.

The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(),  .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes itself, see .one()

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for getting back to me, I do appreciate your help.

In the end I decided to do this in CSS with a click to trick the action via a very small JS.
I borrowed the code fomr here

https://codepen.io/thetallweeks/pen/boinE

```
<div class="box transform">
</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me"></input>

  ================

.box {
  background-color: #218D9B;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.transform {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -o-transition: all 2s ease;  
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease;  
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.transform-active {
  background-color: #45CEE0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
  ================

$("#button").click(function() {
  $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');
});
```